# LWC - For each Quote, render it as a vertical column in the Grid

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds-grid

I'm trying to create this with LWC
[image]

selectedQuoteList loads and iterates just fine. I'm just not able to format the grid as you see in the mockup above. Instead, the data is rendered stacked, like this:

```
Vendor Name
Quote Name
Status
Purchase Agreement
0013k00002vtDONAA2
0028
New
a4vDL0000013VfjYAE
0013k00002io4VgAAI
0029
New
a4vDL0000013VfjYAE
0013k00002uvee6AAA
0030
New
a4vDL0000013VfjYAE
```

Here's my code

```
<template if:true={selectedQuoteList}>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--vertical">
        <div class="slds-col">
            <span>Vendor Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            <span>Quote Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            <span>Status</span>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            <span>Purchase Agreement</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <template for:each={selectedQuoteList} for:item="quote">
        <div key={quote.Id} class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
            <div class="slds-col">
                <span>{quote.Vendor_Name__c}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <span>{quote.Name}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <span>{quote.Status__c}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <span>{quote.Purchase_Agreement__c}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display the data in that particular format(using slds classes) you will need to nest vertical grids inside a normal grid, here is a sample code to give you an idea of how to approach this:

I recommend you should read about how grid layout works to understand this better

**HTML**

```
    <template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical header">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">Vendor Name</div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">Quote Name</div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">Status</div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">Purchase Agreement</div>
        </div>
        <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical content" key ={account.id}>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12 highlighted">{account.vendorName}</div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">{account.name}</div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">{account.status}</div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">{account.purchaseAgreement}</div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

**js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class StackedVerticalGrid extends LightningElement {
    accounts = [
        {
            id: "1",
            name: "Company 1",
            vendorName: "Vendor 1",
            status: "Status 1",
            purchaseAgreement: "Agreement 1"
        }, {
            id: "2",
            name: "Company 2",
            vendorName: "Vendor 2",
            status: "Status 2",
            purchaseAgreement: "Agreement 2"
        }, {
            id: "4",
            name: "Company 3",
            vendorName: "Vendor 3",
            status: "Status 3",
            purchaseAgreement: "Agreement 3"
        },
    ];
}
```

**css**

```
.slds-col {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

.header {
    background: #d0e2f3;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: min-content;
}

.highlighted {
    background-color: #d9ead3;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of this for my LWC implementation. Anyone here can help translate this to LWC? And why does grid have a vertical option, if it can't be used for my used case?

Comment: @RyanMcNeely Updated my answer to use slds-grid_vertical in the right way, I hope it helps